# Quick way to find the cause of incomplete implementation warning

Tags: ios, warnings

Recently, I was cleaning up my class which had a lot of unused methods and variables. When I built my project, xCode gave a warning of `Incomplete implementation`. The class is huge and it took me a lot of time to find out which method was not implemented in the `.m`. To prevent spending so much time on this warning in the future, I would like to know if there's a quicker way to find out the unimplemented methods. I might be missing some built-in feature of xCode!

**EDIT-** (From the answers) Just in case you feel the need to visualize what is to be done, take a look at this:

[image]

First, click on the warning in the break-points tab to see the warning details in a yellow tab as below. A single click on the highlighted part will take you straight to the incomplete methods.

Comment: @KevinBallard It'd be helpful if you could list some cases when it can cause harm :)

Comment: When someone sends a message to your class that it claims to implement, and then you crash because it doesn't implement the method. Or if you declare conformance to a protocol but don't implement all of the required methods, and someone sends a message to you because you claim to implement the protocol, but you don't really implement it and so you crash.

Comment: @KevinBallard Duly noted and question edited.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- You will see the yellow sign of warning next to the `@implementation
  Classname` in the `.m` file ..
- Click a couple of times on the yellow symbol and Xcode will take you
  straight to the required method..

> Edit (Since comment has received a lot of votes.)

The above one is fast way..and it might not work in future version of Xcode

Proper Way (as given by @alex gray)

1. In editor-> Go to Issue Navigator
2. There you can find each warning with Xcode jumping to the issue directly on click.Revealing the warning using drop down also lets you know more detail about the issue

Comment: Ah...precisely what I was looking for

Comment: what @shubhank means by "Click a couple of times" is.. if in the editor:  click on the yellow exclamation indicator in the left sidebar, or otherwise "show issue" in navigator… then, IN the navigator… click on the disclosure triangle to "expand" the issue.. which will in turn show you the actually missing method.

Comment: I love you, alex gray. This drove me crazy for the entire first year of iOS programming.

Comment: Great Tip! You can also right click the triangle near the offending line and select "Reveal in Issue Navigator", once in the issue navigator you can expand the arrow downwards to reveal the offending method etc

Answer (score 9):

Click on the exclamation mark in Navigators Bar (or <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>, or `View -> Navigators -> Show Issue Navigator`), then click on the disclosure button with `Semantic Issue - Incomplete implementation` and then on the warning.

See example below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the navigator click on the disclosure triangle to "expand" the issue, which will in turn show you the actually missing method.

(this is a copy of `alex gray` comment because appropriate location of it in answers)

Comment: I can only give this a +1 because @Shubhank's way is quicker!

Comment: I was not able to use what @Shubhank described - it does not work for me - that why I was looking for other answer and found it in comments.

Comment: What version of xCode are you on? The steps for 4.1+(couldn't check on lower versions) : Click on the warnings triangle pertaining to the `Incomplete implementation` which shows the detail of the warning in a yellow bar in continuation with the warning triangle. Double click this yellow bar and you'll be taken straight to the methods

Comment: I use XCode 4.3.3. I double clicked on yellow triangle and then on the yellow line "Incomplete implementation" to the right of code line  "@implementation Class1". I double clicked other yellow triangle which I observed, but this does not help (Just to clarify: I declared method in .h-file, but does not provide implementation in .m-file)

Comment: I've added a snapshot in the question for your reference.

Comment: I did what you described - it does not work for me. Have you tried it in XCode 4.3.3? If so I will try more thoroughly

Comment: Hmm...I tested this on 4.4.5 and it didn't work! I'm blown! It's difficult to believe that the support for a feature like this has been taken away. Now, either there might be a hidden setting to turn this on or it might just be a bug with the newer versions of xCode!

Comment: As for me it is quite logical, especially for Apple to avoid redundant things, because more natural to press disclose trianlge, and exlamation mark is not user control. Anyway, it is good that we clarified :)